# Failed to launch the browser process Puppeteer on shared hosting due to libatk-bridge-2.0 missing

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer, shared-hosting

I created a Nodejs app with Puppeteer. This app works fine on localhost but when I uploaded it on a shared hosting I faced this issue. **Failed to launch the browser process!PATH/14/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-901912/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md**
I can't install it due to lack of permission in shared hosting even support team couldn't help me. Please I need your help folks

How to install libatk-bridge-2.0 on shared hosting and solve the problem.

Comment: You won't get that working on shared hosting, you need a proper vps